# as3 calling jQuery function

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, flash, z-index

I need flash to talk to jQuery.

Here is my Flash code:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) 
{
 ExternalInterface.call('function(){ MyFunction(); }');
ExternalInterface.call('function(){ alert("Praise Be Jesus Christ!"); }');
}
```

The "Alert" works great. My function does not.

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function()
  { 
  $("#flashContentABOVE").click(MyFunction);



  function MyFunction()
  {
            $("#flashContentABOVE").css("z-index", 4 );

  }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Try placing it outside the ready function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `<script>` tag at the bottom of your html file (before the closing `<body>`), and take out the `document.ready()` function.

Comment: Awesome! That's it! I can't even click "That's correct" yet since you answered so fast. Thank you. I will check it soon. Are you sure removing the document.ready() function won't give me issues elsewhere? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: `document.ready()` catches an event that's fired when the DOM is loaded and ready to be manipulated. Since we've put the `script` tag at the bottom of the page, we already know for sure that the browser has loaded the elements above.

Comment: Any idea how to call an actionscript 3 function from jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call MyFunction directly from your swf.  I always call ExternalInterface like:

```
ExternalInterface.call("funcName","param1","param2");
```

Comment: Any idea how to call an actionscript 3 function from jQuery?